# How to add markers on legend and graph - matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, markers

I have the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Average GPA and Standard Deviation per course combination', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Standard Deviation of Average GPA', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Average GPA', fontsize=12)

colors = ['#E74C3C', '#76448A', '#3498DB', '#17A589', '#F1C40F', '#F39C12', '#CA6F1E', '#B3B6B7', '#34495E',
          '#F5B7B1']
marker = ['.','v','^','1','2','8','p','P','x','X']
g = sns.scatterplot(x=all_stdev, y=all_gpas, hue=final_courses)
g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

the **all_stdev, all_gpas, final_courses are lists** and change everytime based on the user, since these are recommendations for the user based on input. The result I get is the following for a particular student:

[image]

I tried putting markers in order for them to be more easy to understand from the user(the results) but no matter the things I tried I did not manage to do it. The markers would appear in the graph with same color and the legend would still have all colors as shown above. I need to add the markers to the graph and legend as well. Is there a way to do it? I have a list with markers that I would like to use in the code provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the markers and the colors as a parameter to the scatterplot.
There still is another problem with the markers. Seaborn complains: *Filled and line art markers cannot be mixed*. So you need to select either [filled or line art](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html) [markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/markers_api.html).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Average GPA and Standard Deviation per course combination', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Standard Deviation of Average GPA', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Average GPA', fontsize=12)

colors = ['#E74C3C', '#76448A', '#3498DB', '#17A589', '#F1C40F', '#F39C12', '#CA6F1E', '#B3B6B7', '#34495E', '#F5B7B1']
# marker = ['.', 'v', '^', '1', '2', '8', 'p', 'P', 'x', 'X']
marker = ['o', 'v', '^', '8', '*', 'P', 'D', 'X', 's', 'p']
N = 30
final_courses = np.random.randint(1,11, N) * 10
all_stdev = np.random.uniform(0, 2, N)
all_gpas = np.random.uniform(3, 4, N)
g = sns.scatterplot(x=all_stdev, y=all_gpas, hue=final_courses, style=final_courses, palette=colors, markers=marker)
g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]